# The type or namespace nvarchar could not be found - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, namespaces

This is my code:

```
public class kdd
{
    public nvarchar duration; 
}
```

I am getting an error: The type or namespace nvarchar dould not be found, after some research I found a solution to add SqlTypes namespace but I am still getting the error even after adding the namespace.

The namespaces I have tried are,

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChar;
using System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString;
```

I would be glad if someone helps me out in this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit.....

I am trying to create a class called kdd. Something similar to the below code,

```
public class Customer 
{ 
    public int CustId; 

    public string Name; 

    public decimal Balance; 

    public DateTime AddedDate; 

}
```

Comment: `nvarchar` is an SQL data type, not a C# / .NET data type.  You need to use standard .NET data types in your code. To provide more assistance than that, you're going to need to explain more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the details you asked.

Comment: As an aside, it's a bit strange to have a field called "duration" that is a SQL `nvarchar` or a C# `string`.  What data are you storing in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvarchar` is a SQL keyword not a C# keyword. So you can not have variable with type nvarchar.

Following line would give you build error.

```
public nvarchar duration;
```

You have to use a relevant C# type here. In your case you can use a `string`.

```
public string duration;
```

Comment: Your answer solved my error, I will mark it as answer shortly. Thanks!